# CodeIgniter page doesn't work while calling as OracleBI XML file

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle-bi

i'm calling xml stream which in CodeIgniter project from Oracle BI as xml file data source. Normally it works properly when i called through url manually, even it works fine in same server outside CodeIgniter and different server as well. Samples as following, i checked everything relating to the authorization (such as IP constraints) but i couldn't find any solution related the problem.

***Doesn't work;***

```
http://test.myintranet/report/index.php/ws?param=130
```

***Works fine thats;***

```
http://test.kolkhoba.net/ws.php?param=130
http://test.myintranet/report/test/index.php?param=130
```

***Config settings;***

```
config->routes.php
    $route['ws'] = 'WS_Controller/index';
config->config.php
    $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%\.:_\-&=';
```

***WS_Controller/index (Xml content);***

```
<?php
    class WS_Controller extends MY_Controller {
      public function index() {     
       $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
       $path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
       $queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
       $url = $domain . $path . "?" . $queryString;
       mail("mail@myintranet", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ." called ws xml service at " . date("h:i:sa"), $url);

       $param = $_GET['param'];

       header("Content-type: text/xml");
       $inner = "";
       $inner .= "<report>";
       $inner .= sprintf("<id>%s</id>", $param);
       $inner .= "</report>";

       echo sprintf("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><root>%s</root>", $inner);
     }
   }
?>
```

***Xml Stream;***

```
<root>
   <report>
     <id>130</id>
   </report>
</root>
```

Comment: try $route['ws'] = 'WS_Controller';

Comment: also try $config['url_suffix'] = ''; in config/config.php

Comment: and $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'